# Chrome sending of packets to random destinations upon reconnect/disconnect

Tags: google-chrome, http, fiddler

Noticed an interesting thing whilst debugging one of my websocket applications that Google Chrome will push out 3 http requests upon a network connection status changing;

Quite disconcerting and looks almost as if some malware is checking out to a random server.

I don't quite understand the why though since they all return a `502` or have no response code at all since the destination does not exist.

On Disconnect:

[image: Connection Down]

Reconnect:

[image: Connection Up]

I guess the main question is this normal and what the use is; howcome they wouldn't go for a dns lookup that actually exists?

Comment: *howcome they wouldn't go for a dns lookup that actually exists?* Actually exists relative to who? Relative to my PC? `zcpluzmxwt` probably won't get anywhere. Relative to your malware-riddled box? `zcpluzmxwt` is probably in your `hosts` file.

Comment: @ta.speot.is nothing in there that looks anything like the above, like I said its only when chrome is running that these requests are seen.

Comment: thanks for the comment though, @ta.speot.is ; seems the worst is always the first option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I remember, this is a special feature of Chrome. This feature is used to help to detect if your provider specially process invalid dns entries. [chromium bugtracker - latest message](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47262)

Comment: :) thanks, seems like there were quite a few people with the same observation and theory. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks alarming but is apparently normal and intended behaviour in Chrome.

In order to use the address/location bar for searches and not just URLs, Chrome needs to check that the entered text isn't a valid domain before it can treat it as a search term. However, some IPSs serve advertising pages in response to non-existent domains ([DNS Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking)), which would make it appear that every domain exists! To test for this, Chrome will query some random, likely bogus single-word domains and see if they map to the same IP address. If they do, Chrome can assume that the upstream ISP is performing DNS hijacking.

See also [Chrome: DNS requests with random DNS names: malware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363512/chrome-dns-requests-with-random-dns-names-malware), [Chromium issue 47262](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47262)

Comment: Wouldn’t say it’s harmless.  If they can redirect when you attempting to view a domain that doesn’t exist they can redirect you when a domain does exist

Comment: @Ramhound Certainly DNS hijacking in general is far from harmless, but the original question seemed to be asking specifically about Chrome's unusual behaviour. I'll see if I can reword the answer better.